Read an article about connecting a hot tub to a heat pump, looking for details
There does not seem to be a lot out there yet. So the question is whether or not anyone has some ideas. I have a new heat pump, which happens to be right near where I am going to put a new hot tub. I am a tad confused, I don't think they are saying you can use the one heat pump to do both but that maybe you can take some of the heat coming off the one to make the other one more efficient? like how the hybrid water heaters work?

Do you mean "heat pump water heater"? A "heat pump" is a refrigeration device that can transfer heat from one side to the other. Window ACs are heat pumps, too, for example.

There are systems for heating a pool with the heat removed from a house by AC/heat-pump.  Is something like that potentially what you saw?

@Triplefault so yeah my question is not super clear, I am kind of asking about both: 1. can you get a hot tub water heater that is a heat pump (like the hybrid water heaters)? and 2. I read that if you have a heat pump you can connect the two so then the AC is on in the house it's expelling heat, the other heat pump would suck it in like the hybrids and have to do very little to put it into the water?

There are 'air to air' and 'air to water' heat pumps, which distribute heat or cool around the home via air or water respectively.  If you have an A2W heat pump, it outputs hot water that can be suitable to heat a hot tub.  Because of the pool chemicals you would probably need to use a heat exchanger to transfer heat from the A2W output water to the pool water.
A 'heat pump water heater' is a version of an A2W heat pump, but if it is intended for generating bathroom hot water it isn't necessarily optimal for heating hot tub water, although it may still be possible.

An Air source heat pump will produce some heat when removing heat from air in a home. That heat can be captured and use to heat another source.
While this can be achieved well in the newer heatpump water heaters, the reality is the methods and materials needed to do this is not practical to be used in a retrofit situation. ( Hooking up your hot tub to a heatpump.)
A more efficient and cheep way to get free heat is to add solar heat to your hot tub.  This can be solar panels or simple as placing a coil of black poly pipe on your roof and plumbing it into the heater circulation system. (I did this to my own hot tub and it worked great...but I'm in fla. There are more specific details to the installation, that should be asked about in another question.)

I've seen systems where a pool is used as a heat sink (which heats the pool) and I think it was a retrofit. It makes a lot of sense for a relatively cool pool but I'm not sure how that works for a hot tub since the water is usually kept at a high temp.
